# Copying and Pasting an image with the path in a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I need help copying and pasting an image with the path in a cell.

In F2 I have my Image Path C:\Users\gaetan.affolter\Desktop\test.jpg but the path is changing all the time (I need Variable F2)

I got an error "Unable to get the insert properity of the picture Class"

```
 Sub Copiarimg()

Dim pic As Picture

With ActiveSheet

Set pic = .Pictures.Insert(Range("f2").Value)

With .Range("e9:g22")
pic.Top = .Top
pic.Left = .Left
pic.Width = .Width
pic.Height = .Height

End With
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to work ok. Are you missing a "." before `Range("f2").Value`?

You can use the `Dir` function to test that the pic file exists.

```
Sub Copiarimg()

Dim pic As Picture
Dim picSource As String

    With ActiveSheet
        picSource = .Range("f2").Value
        If Dir$(picSource) <> "" Then
            Set pic = .Pictures.Insert(picSource)

            With .Range("e9:g22")
                pic.Top = .Top
                pic.Left = .Left
                pic.Width = .Width
                pic.Height = .Height
            End With
        Else
            MsgBox "Cannot find the file " & picSource
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I see no problem with your code, check two things:

1. Does your file really exist, 2. Does the path contain an extra space at the end